# Print mixed line by line of two strings in C++?

Tags: c++

i have two strings `align_A` and `align_B` that have some characters, how i can print first line of `align_A` then in below (next line) print first line of `align_B` then in below print second line of `align_A` and in next line print second line of `align_B` and so on. i use such code that insert characters that can situate in lines (80 characters).

```
int len=align_A.length()/80;
...
```

i don't write continuation code because I'm working on it and not ready.
this is complexity, is there another way (such functions) to perform this action with simplicity?
NOTE: there isn't a line specifier such as `\0` or`\n` in string variables.

Comment: Are the lengths of alignA and alignB multiples of 80? Are their lengths equal?

Comment: Are these fixed-width lines, or are they delimited by, say, `'\n'`s?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: I counted characters that can print in a line of screen. in each line of screen, 80 characters can printed.

Comment: @milad_b *80*? In fact, it can be from 1 to 9999.

Comment: @johnchen902: you're right. i suppose that it's 80 in windows, dos screen.

Comment: @milad_b right click the title bar, click `Properties`, choose `layout` tab, and you can change the width of window.

Comment: @johnchen902: you're right. i had not seen this property.

Answer (score 1):

Use an std::string. With it you can use  [find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to find the next newline character. Then you can use [substr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to split the string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string str = "aasdasdasda\nasdasdasd\nasdasdasd";

    int index = str.find('\n'); // Find position of newline
    std::cout << str.substr(0, index) << std::endl; // Print string until newline
    std::cout << str.substr(0, 10 ) << std::endl; // Print the first 80 charcters
}
```

Comment: @milad_b No, I just used them to test the finding of newline charcters. Just ignore them and use the `str.substr(0, 10 )` version.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `char array` and `stdio`:

```
#include <cstdio>
// #include <cstdlib>
#define SCREEN_SIZE_STR "80"

int main(){
    const char s1[] =
        "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
        "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
        "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
        "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
        "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    const char s2[] = 
        "abcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnop"
        "abcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnop"
        "abcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnop"
        "abcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnop"
        "abcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnop";

    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    while(s1[i1] != '\0' && s2[i2] != '\0'){ // print both string
        i1 += printf("%."SCREEN_SIZE_STR"s", s1 + i1);
        i2 += printf("%."SCREEN_SIZE_STR"s", s2 + i2);
    }
    while(s1[i1] != '\0') // print the remaining of s1
        i1 += printf("%."SCREEN_SIZE_STR"s", s1 + i1);
    while(s2[i2] != '\0') // print the remaining of s2
        i2 += printf("%."SCREEN_SIZE_STR"s", s2 + i2);
    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If you're using `std::string`:

```
const char *s1 = string1.c_str();
const char *s2 = string2.c_str();
```

Comment: It's OK but my variables are string. what can i do with them?

Comment: @milad_b `c_str()` See my answer.